# Escape newline character using textview in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to display the line

```
printf("a*b : %.2f\n",a*b);
```

in android studio using textview. It is implementing `\n` as new line instead of displaying it as text.

How can I escape the `\n` so that it displays "\n" as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the `\` character, try `\\n` instead of `\n`:

```
printf("ab : %.2f\\n",ab);
```

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer, please :)